# Check if product has specific tag in Prestashop 1.6.1.4

Tags: php, caching, smarty, prestashop

I'd like to check if a product has a certain tag.  If it does I'd like to display some text.  Below is the sample of what I've done. It works.  The only problem is I get errors.

```
 {if in_array('rent', $product->tags.1)}
      <img id="turnKeyimg" alt="TurnKey Rental Option" src="{$tpl_uri}img/key.png"/>
      <h3>TurnKey Rental Option</h3>
      <p>Also available for immediate rental.<br />Request a quote today</p>
 {/if}
```

The error log have entries like this:

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /cache/smarty/compile/94/4d/52/944d5284e871d0de7a0c6b84ebb2089ad579ed8b.file.product.tpl.php on line 330

Line 330 in the cache looks like this:

```
<?php if (in_array('rent',$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1])) {?> 
     <img id="turnKeyimg" alt="TurnKey Rental Option" 
     src="<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tpl_uri']->value;
?>
```

What did I do wrong to cause these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error messages I added a check if an array existed.  No more errors.

```
 {if (isset($product->tags) && $product->tags)}
    {if in_array('rent', $product->tags.1)}
      <img id="turnKeyimg" alt="TurnKey Rental Option" src="{$tpl_uri}img/key.png"/>
      <h3>TurnKey Rental Option</h3>
      <p>Also available for immediate rental.<br />Request a quote today</p>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in ...

Simple, [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function expects second argument to be an array, but you're passing `NULL` as second argument.

You have to first check whether `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1]` is an array or not, and then do your `in_array(...)` operation.

```
<?php if (is_array($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1]) && in_array('rent',$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1])) {?> 
     <img id="turnKeyimg" alt="TurnKey Rental Option" 
     src="<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tpl_uri']->value;
?>
```

Comment: How would this look using smarty?  I can't use the <?php.  
I tried this: {if (is_array($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1]) && in_array('rent',$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value->tags[1]))} but the check no longer works. I looked at a product that has the tag rent and the text I want to display did not show.

Comment: @N13Design I'm not an expert in Smarty template but have you tried this approach, [https://pastebin.com/ZBy4eNJe](https://pastebin.com/ZBy4eNJe) ?

Comment: There's something in there Prestashop doesn't like.  It broke the page.

Comment: I added `{if (isset($product->tags) && $product->tags)}  {/if}` around the in_array statement.  I reset the error log.  Hopefully that works.